# How to set diferent levels of logging for each file in module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-module

How do you choose the level of logging in modules?

I have an application with various files,
I worked for understand the logging module, and drop print() 
My goals with logging is flexibility switching logging levels from diferents part of the code (modules)
I do it only from the main entry point function:

Here is what i have:

```
APP/PartA/Script1.py
APP/PartA/Script2.py
APP/Other/Tools.py
APP/main.py
```

First module:

```
#/PartA/Script1.py
import logging
from PartA.Script2 import *

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Logger Always on debug level:
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler1 = logging.StreamHandler()
handler1.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('\n%(levelname)s  %(name)s'))

logger.addHandler(handler1)

def add_ten(n)
    ten_added = add_five(n) + 5
    return ten_added
```

Second module:

```
#/PartA/Script2.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Logger Always on debug level:
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler2 = logging.StreamHandler()
handler2.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('\n%(levelname)s  %(name)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)s \n%(message)s'))

logger.addHandler(handler2)

def add_five(n):
    return n + 5
```

Main entry point:

```
#main.py
import logging
from PartA.Script1 import *
from PartA.Script2 import *



logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Logger is always on debug mode..
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Mainhandler:
handler = logging.StreamHandler()

handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Here i control the logs levels from the other modules:
handler2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler1.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Thats working , as i just have to change the handlers setlevels in the main function, but i dont think it is very pythonic, having to set all the loggers on DEBUG level always seems strange, 
And very repetitive code to do it for any new .py file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is best practice in python to not configure any logging handlers/formatters inside your module, just use the NullHandler. The configuration of handlers is done inside the application using the module.

So the following should be sufficient inside the module.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Comment: So i cant use same logger names in the diferent modules right? Finally get it ! thank you! If i use only one handler in main.py, it should always be on debug level, Then i change level or change handler the diferents loggers.